# React Native - Image picker with images from online?

Tags: image, react-native, google-places-api

I am currently using Google Places API on react native to get an array of photo URLs from a specific site. However, I would like my user to pick the ones that they want us to save in our servers (multiple images), and also set as primary picture for their profile.

I've been looking through many image picker libraries on React Native but all of them focus on getting data from the device, which is perfect, but not what I am looking for.

I would like to know if anyone has found any library like [react-native-image-crop-picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker) that lets the user select multiple images from an array of image urls that I pass.

Comment: Luis Rizo did you find any solution? I want to search images through google and select one of them to store in my server.

Comment: Hey @David, I ended up making fetch calls to various Google APIs (places-autocomplete -> places-details -> place-photo), and parse the response, which was an array of photos, and send it to a custom-made photo viewer (ListView with Touchable items).